# Dojo charting - rightmost axis title getting cut in half

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I am using dojo to create a bar chart with multiple vertical axes (one for an actual count, the other for a percentage), and when I do, the title for the right axis always gets cut off (i.e., the half of it that's furthest from the chart gets cut off by the edge of the chart). I've already tried using `chart.resize(w,h)`, but this only shrinks the data in the chart, while maintaining the same margins from the edge (and thus the same title cut as before). Does anyone know how to get the title to properly display? For reference, here's the code I'm using, both to create the div node and the chart.

```
chartNode = domConstruct.create("div", {
    id : this.context.viewid + "_ChartNode",
}, this.context.element, "first");

domStyle.set(chartNode, {
    width : "800px",
    height : "400px"
});

var chart = new Chart(chartNode);

chart.addPlot("default", {
    type : "Columns",
    markers : true,
    gap : 5
});
chart.addPlot("something", {
    type : "Columns",
    vAxis : "percent"
});

chart.addAxis("x", {
    title : "Person",
    titleOrientation : "away",
    minorTicks : false,
    majorTickStep : 1,
    dropLabels : false
});
chart.addAxis("y", {
    vertical : true,
    fixLower : "includeZero",
    title : "Count",
    min : 0,
    max : data[0].totalSubmitted
});
chart.addAxis("percent", {
    title : "Percentage",
    titleGap : 20,
    vertical : true,
    leftBottom : false,
    fixLower : "includeZero",
    min : 0,
    max : 100,
})

chart.addSeries("y", data);
chart.render();
```

Edit: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pme2.png) is what my code is actually generating, with the cutoff being highlighted in red.

Comment: Any chance you can include an image of what you are seeing??

Comment: Yeah, just uploaded and linked it. Not enough rep to do inline images yet :(

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is with no HTML.  In your web browser, hold the pointer over the graph or text element, right click and select inspect element.  It should give you all the CSS that applies.  It also allows you edit CSS property values to see if it will change the layout to include the label you want to see.  Also, you can hold the pointer over HTML and it will give a lot of valuable information about the layout.

Comment: I went into the HTML with firebug, it turns out it's both an HTML and a dojo issue. While resizing the div that I create in the code doesn't help anything (other than adding whitespace), modifying the HTML generated by dojox/charting does. Specifically, an svg tag within the div, as well as a rect tag within that must be modified to fix the fill and border, respectively. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Not sure if I should add this as the answer to this question or just leave this all in the comments.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  Can just leave all this as comments and you can click the up arrow on my comment.  Remember you can add your own css styles to dojo widgets which should override defaults too.  Good luck with your project.